# Не отображается карта при использовании координат

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-maps-api

Прошлый вопрос задавал по поводу определения кординат по названию города с этим уже решили. Спасибо огромное. Но теперь встает вопрос другой: когда я использую полученные координаты, чтобы установить новый центр карты, то карта на отображается вовсе. Подскажите что может быть и как это решить. Вот кусок кода

```js
$('.select1').change(function() {
  var city = $(".selected1").text();

  var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(city);
  myGeocoder.then(
    function(res) {
      var cordinatsss = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();

      mapMap.setCenter(new YMaps.GeoPoint(cordinatsss), 9);
    },
    function(err) {
      alert('Ошибка');
    }
  );
});
```

изначально центр карты уже установлен задача поменять центр в зависимости от города

Comment: а если так -- mapMap.setCenter(cordinatsss); ?...

Comment: Всем спасибо разобрался. Дело в том что эта строчка образует массив var cordinatsss = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();
А при указании кординат в setCenter массив не принимается соответственно если сделать так mapMap.setCenter(new YMaps.GeoPoint(cordinatsss[0], cordinatsss[1]), 9); Все работает